# Bot orienting to same direction regardless of Quaternion value in Moveit

Tags: moveit, ros-noetic, manipulator, ur5, moveit-commander

I am trying to control a simulated UR5e bot using ROS. For trajectory planning and execution i am using Moveit. The issue is that when I give a Pose to Moveit, the bot reaches the position (XYZ) just fine but no matter what Quaternion value I set, the bot always aligns itself facing upward. Here is the code which I am using for moving the bot. This python ROS node subscribe to a /coords topic and execute a cartesian path.
For debugging I have tried to give only one Pose to the bot, but the bot still aligns itself in upward direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function
from six.moves import input

import sys
import copy
import rospy
import numpy as np
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseArray, Point, Quaternion

try:
    from math import pi, tau, dist, fabs, cos
except:  # For Python 2 compatibility
    from math import pi, fabs, cos, sqrt

    tau = 2.0 * pi

    def dist(p, q):
        return sqrt(sum((p_i - q_i) ** 2.0 for p_i, q_i in zip(p, q)))


from std_msgs.msg import String, Float64MultiArray
from moveit_commander.conversions import pose_to_list


def all_close(goal, actual, tolerance):
    """
    Convenience method for testing if the values in two lists are within a tolerance of each other.
    For Pose and PoseStamped inputs, the angle between the two quaternions is compared (the angle
    between the identical orientations q and -q is calculated correctly).
    @param: goal       A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
    @param: actual     A list of floats, a Pose or a PoseStamped
    @param: tolerance  A float
    @returns: bool
    """
    if type(goal) is list:
        for index in range(len(goal)):
            if abs(actual[index] - goal[index]) > tolerance:
                return False

    elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped:
        return all_close(goal.pose, actual.pose, tolerance)

    elif type(goal) is geometry_msgs.msg.Pose:
        x0, y0, z0, qx0, qy0, qz0, qw0 = pose_to_list(actual)
        x1, y1, z1, qx1, qy1, qz1, qw1 = pose_to_list(goal)
        d = dist((x1, y1, z1), (x0, y0, z0))
        cos_phi_half = fabs(qx0 * qx1 + qy0 * qy1 + qz0 * qz1 + qw0 * qw1)
        return d <= tolerance and cos_phi_half >= cos(tolerance / 2.0)

    return True


class UR_move(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UR_move, self).__init__()

        rospy.Subscriber('/coords', PoseArray, self.coords_callback)

        robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()

        scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()


        group_name = "ur_5e"
        move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)

        display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher(
            "/move_group/display_planned_path",
            moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,
            queue_size=10,
        )

        planning_frame = move_group.get_planning_frame()
        print("============ Planning frame: %s" % planning_frame)

        eef_link = move_group.get_end_effector_link()
        print("============ End effector link: %s" % eef_link)

        group_names = robot.get_group_names()
        print("============ Available Planning Groups:", robot.get_group_names())

        print("============ Printing robot state")
        print(robot.get_current_state())
        print("")

        self.robot = robot
        self.scene = scene
        self.move_group = move_group
        self.display_trajectory_publisher = display_trajectory_publisher
        self.planning_frame = planning_frame
        self.eef_link = eef_link
        self.group_names = group_names

    def coords_callback(self, coords_msg):
        try:
            cartesian_plan, fraction = self.plan_cartesian_path(coords_msg)
            self.execute_plan(cartesian_plan)
        except Exception as e:
            rospy.logerr(f"Error processing /coords message: {str(e)}")

    def plan_cartesian_path(self, coords_msg, scale=1):

        move_group = self.move_group
        #rospy.wait_for_message('/coords', PoseArray)
        # coords_msg = rospy.wait_for_message('/coords', PoseArray)
        poses = coords_msg.poses    
        waypoints = []
        hpose = move_group.get_current_pose().pose
        # print("COORDS:",poses)
        # for pose in poses:
        #     x, y, z = pose.position.x, pose.position.y, pose.position.z
        #     xo, yo, zo ,w = pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y,pose.orientation.z, pose.orientation.w 
        #     wpose = move_group.get_current_pose().pose
        #     wpose.position.z = z 
        #     wpose.position.y = y 
        #     wpose.position.x = x
        #     wpose.orientation.w = w
        #     wpose.orientation.x = xo
        #     wpose.orientation.y = yo
        #     wpose.orientation.z = zo 
    
        #     waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
        # #TEST
        wpose = move_group.get_current_pose().pose
        print(hpose)
        wpose.position.x = hpose.position.x
        wpose.position.y = hpose.position.y
        wpose.position.z = hpose.position.z
        wpose.orientation.x = 0.1
        wpose.orientation.y = 0
        wpose.orientation.z = 0.1
        wpose.orientation.w = 0

        waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
        print(waypoints)
        # waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(hpose))
        (plan, fraction) = move_group.compute_cartesian_path(
            waypoints, 0.01, 0.0  # waypoints to follow  # eef_step
        )  

        return plan, fraction

    def display_trajectory(self, plan):

        robot = self.robot
        display_trajectory_publisher = self.display_trajectory_publisher


        display_trajectory = moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory()
        display_trajectory.trajectory_start = robot.get_current_state()
        display_trajectory.trajectory.append(plan)
        # Publish
        display_trajectory_publisher.publish(display_trajectory)


    def execute_plan(self, plan):

        move_group = self.move_group

        move_group.execute(plan, wait=True)



    def main():
        try:
            print("")
            print("----------------------------------------------------------")
            print("MoveIt UR5e Move Group")
            print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    
            tutorial = UR_move()
            moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
            rospy.init_node("ur_move", anonymous=True)
    
            rospy.spin()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

[image: This is how the bot looks after executing trajectory]

So far I have tried to use set goal pose method apart from compute_cartesian path method, but the behaviour is still same.
How can i fix this?